# WPF MVVM ListView does not update when changing in MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, listview, mvvm

I am new to WPF and MVVM, ListView does not get updated when changing item in Database. Does anyone have any example on how they accomplished this?

Here is my Listview:

```
<ListView DataContext="{Binding  Source={StaticResource changpassVM}, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Row="1" Name="lstUser"  ItemsSource="{Binding TableFromMySqlEdit,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Path= SelectChangPass,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"                      

                          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = "True"
                          >
                    <ListView.View >
                        <GridView>
  <GridViewColumn local:GridViewColumnVisibilityManager.IsVisible="False" Header="Id"   HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderStyle }" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"  />
                            <GridViewColumn  HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderStyle }" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="Auto" Header="Tên Người Dùng" />
                            <GridViewColumn  HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderStyle }" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Pass,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="Auto" Header="Mật Khẩu" />
                            <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderStyle }" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Address}" Width="Auto" Header="Địa Chỉ" />
                            <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderStyle }" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Email}" Header="Email"  Width="Auto"/>
                            <GridViewColumn HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderStyle}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Createdate}" Header="Ngày Tạo" Width="Auto"/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

this is my viewmodel:

```
public class changPassViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region property


//    private DataTable _TableFromMySql;
    private ObservableCollection<User> _TableFromMySql;

    private readonly UserRepository ur;

    private readonly changPassUser chuser;

    private  ICommand _editchangUserCmd;

    #endregion end property

    #region intialiti

    public changPassViewModel()
   {
       ur = new UserRepository();

        //_TableFromMySql = new List<changPassUser>
       // {
       //     new changPassUser {ID=1, Name ="Pro1", Pass="10"},
       //     new changPassUser{ID=2, Name="BAse2", Pass="12"}
       // };
       chuser = new changPassUser();

     //  _TableFromMySql = ur.get_user_DataTable();
       _TableFromMySql = ur.getData();
      //this.DataContext = 
       _editchangUserCmd = new RelayCommand(Edit, CanEdit);

   }
    #endregion intia

    #region

    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return chuser.user_Id  ;
        }
        set
        {
            chuser.user_Id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return chuser.user_Name;
        }
        set
        {
            chuser.user_Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }

    }

    public string Pass
    {

        get
        {
            return chuser.user_Pass;
        }
        set
        {
            chuser.user_Pass = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Pass");
        }
    }

    public string Email
    {

        get
        {
            return chuser.user_Email;
        }
        set
        {
            chuser.user_Email = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Email");
        }
    }
    public string Address
    {

        get
        {
            return chuser.user_Address;
        }
        set
        {
            chuser.user_Address = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Address");
        }
    }


    #endregion

    #region ListView
    public ObservableCollection<User> TableFromMySqlEdit
    {
        get
        {
            return _TableFromMySql;
        }
        set
        {
            _TableFromMySql = value;
          //  OnPropertyChanged("TableFromMySqlEdit");
        }
    }   
   //public IList<changPassUser> TableFromMySql
   //{
   //    get
   //    {
   //        return _TableFromMySql;
   //    }
   //    set
   //    {
   //        _TableFromMySql = value;
   //    }
   //}
   #endregion end ListView

 //  private ICommand mUpdater;
   public ICommand EditPassuser
   {
       get
       {
           //if (_editchangUserCmd == null){
               // mUpdater = new Updater();
               return _editchangUserCmd;

          // return mUpdater;
       }
       set
       {
           _editchangUserCmd = value;
       }
   }

   public bool CanEdit(object obj)
   {
       if (Name != string.Empty && Pass != string.Empty && Pass != null)
           return true;
       return false;
   }
   public void Edit(object obj)
   {
       string a =   "";
       DateTime dt_edit = DateTime.Now;
       //int Index;
     //  Index = UserRepository.GetIndex();
       for (int i = 0; i < TableFromMySqlEdit.Count; i++)
           if (TableFromMySqlEdit[i].Id == Id)
           {
               a  = _TableFromMySql[i].Pass;
           }

       var user = new User
       {
           Id = Id,
         //  Name = Name,
           Pass = Pass,
          // Email = Email,
          // Address = Address,
           Modifieddate =dt_edit.ToString(),
          // Status = 0
       };



       if (ur.Edit(user))
       {
          // TableFromMySqlEdit. (user);
          // GetIndex(Id);
          // _TableFromMySql[user.Id] = user.Pass;


          // TableFromMySqlEdit = _TableFromMySql;
         //  Pass = user.Pass;
           for (int i = 0; i < TableFromMySqlEdit.Count; i++)
               if (TableFromMySqlEdit[i].Id == Id)
               {
                   TableFromMySqlEdit[i].Pass = Pass;
               }
           ResetUser();

           MessageBox.Show("Thêm người dùng thành công !");
       }
       else
           MessageBox.Show("Thêm thất bại !");
   }
  /* private class Updater : ICommand
   {
       #region ICommand Members
       private changPassUser changUser;
       public Updater()
       {
           changUser = new changPassUser();
       }

       public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
       {
         //  if (changUser.Name != string.Empty &&  changUser.Name != null)// && us.PASS != string.Empty)
          // if (TableFromMySql.Count > 0)
               return true;

          // return false;
       }

       public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

       public void Execute(object parameter)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Bạn có chắc muốn đóng?");
       }

       #endregion
   }
   */

   public User SelectChangPass
    {
       set
       {
          Id = value.Id;

           Name = value.Name;

           Address = value.Address;
           Email = value.Email;
         //  CreateDate = value.user_;
          // ModifiedDate = value.Modifieddate;
          // Status = value.Status;
           Pass = value.Pass;
       }

    }

   private int GetIndex(int Id)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < TableFromMySqlEdit.Count; i++)
           if (TableFromMySqlEdit[i].Id == Id)
           {
               TableFromMySqlEdit[i].Pass = Pass;


           }


       return -1;
   }
   private void ResetUser()
   {
       //  Id = 0;
       Name = string.Empty;

       Pass = string.Empty;
       Address = string.Empty;
       Email = string.Empty;
       // MobileNumber = 0;
   }


   #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

   /// <summary>
   /// Event to which the view's controls will subscribe.
   /// This will enable them to refresh themselves when the binded property changes provided you fire this event.
   /// </summary>
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   /// <summary>
   /// When property is changed call this method to fire the PropertyChanged Event
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
   public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
       //Fire the PropertyChanged event in case somebody subscribed to it
       if (PropertyChanged != null)
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }

   #endregion
}
```

This is my model:

```
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Pass { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
   public string  Email { get; set; }
   public string Createdate { get; set; }
   public string Modifieddate { get; set; }
   public int Status { get; set; }
```

Comment: why your "OnPropertyChanged("TableFromMySqlEdit");" is commented ?

Comment: So, another application changes the database and then you would like to see this change in your app in the ListView?

Comment: Set method not called, but Get,so might this's problem @Vlvaro

Comment: i have one windown and i select one row in my listview on this windown then i edit it on textbox,clik button edit. So, but the value of this row not change @Martin

Comment: If the edit is done in a TextBox, then you should then change your question, because the question says "...when changing item in Database". But where is this text box? In the XAML you posted, I only see the ListView. Can you post the XAML with the text box and any view models associated with it?